# TeXStudio formatting unreadable - how to fix it?

Tags: texstudio

I just downloaded the newest version of TeXStudio for Windows (Using Win10) and I opened a file and see this...
[image]
How do I get rid of this and get a readable text?
I'm using two screens, I have the correct resolution set for each of the screens, all other text editors work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with a multi-monitor setup when using different magnifications on the screens (https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1506/).

As a workaround, disable caching of lines: `Options -> Advanced Editors -> Workarounds -> Disable cache of rendered lines`.

Comment: thanks, useful information! 
I solved it for now accidentally by going somewhere and not having my second screen connected - so I can't test the workaround but I trust you! ;)